# Why are animals (e.g. a dog) considered as not recommended for living inside home, but allowed outdoors?

Tags: belief, animals

Famous masters of Tibetan Tantra, such as Roerich and Blavatskaya wrote that energy vibrations of animals don't match to the frequency of human beings and that's why people shouldn't keep them at home.

I've heard many times that a dog is not recommended to be kept inside home. It was advised not to allow a dog to live in your home, but keep it outside in the yard. Many people though nowadays live with dogs inside home. What is the background for this from the perspective of myths of Hinduism and Indian traditional attitude towards dog and animals in general?

Comment: nope! i am hindu and i own a Dog. Can u share from where you get this information.

Comment: Totally wrong we consider dog as vehicals of some god's like Lord Dattatreya and as substitute form of some demigod's like Bhairava's also in figure of lord Dattatreya we consider Dog's as the four vedas which get attracted to him because he is supreme godhead, the combination of three gods. See this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dattatreya#Dogs and this also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhairava#Iconography

Comment: @Creator Having dogs as vehicles is doesn't mean you will shared bed, room, food with them, You own Cars, Hours or Elephant then will you live with them. a big NO, they good for separate place not in living rooms. The question is related to Keeping animals in home! It is not for not having animals.


And the answer below is explaining much more fact related to this

Comment: @LogicalHindu - The question now is edited and the previous before editing was seriously asking that sanatan dharma considers dogs and other animals as mere puppets that what I replied to, it doesn't mean that we could replace them with our wives or brothers??. It just signifies their value and respect in sanatan dharama.

Comment: @Creator If you want to ask another question you may but updating question is not a good thing!, If you want to change question you may delete this one and ask another question

Comment: It is still asking in the same context, it can be seen in the question itself, not in the title. It was corrected a bit cause initially it was asking about dogs as _bad_ thing, sorry about that, sometimes errors happen and we fix them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any animal is natural, so considering good or bad is personal thing. Hinduism states that animals can not be considered as illegible for Heavan. [Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m17/m17003.htm) epic is proof for this, when Yudhisthira was asked to leave dog when Indra asked him. That dog was Yama himself, and Yudhisthira denies to come to heavan without dog, Indra told that dog is animal who can only go to hell, There is no place in Heaven for persons with dogs Yudhisthira agrees to go to hell.

SadGurudeva Maharaj Lord Dattatreya is widely famous in Hinduism. Dog was one of the 24 teachers to Dattatreya. In any photograph of Lord Dattatreya , you will find 4 dogs, who are considered as 4 Vedas. There is a story that when Lord Dattatreya speaks, even Vedas keep mum. Vedas originated from breath of Lord Datta. Here you can see even Lord himself respects dogs by learning from them and considers them teachers.

Yamadev, Yamraj or Dharmaraj has a dog with three heads. This is mentioned in Rigveda. The dogs are worshipped as a part of a five-day Tihar festival that falls roughly in November every year. In [Hinduism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogs_in_religion), it is believed that dogs guard the doors of Heaven and Hell. 
There is an incranation of shakti whose vehical is dog. Bhairava's vehicle is also a dog.

In Hinduism every creature is considered as originated from Lord Brahma. The properties of animal makes it good or bad for mankind. Actually dogs are the best friends of society but unfortunately worst people are compared with them.

**Why dogs can not be kept inside home?**

Dogs may have many diseases which are allergetic to humans. Natural environment is more suitable to animals.

According to Hinduism, dogs are guards, and guards are at entrance only, there is no place for them inside home.

Comment: a few citations for the last part of your answer would be welcome, especially when you seem so confident about it.